# Regex to match route parameters

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I always have I kinda rough time working with regexes. I'm trying to make a regex that matches routes, when the route has parameters set:

For instance:

- `/post/1` matches `/post/{id}`
- `/post/5/` **doesn't match** `/post/{id}`
- `/post/6/comments/4` matches `/post/{id}/comments/{comment}`
- `/post/a-random-slug` matches `/post/{id}` or `/post/{slug}` (whatever you want to name the param)
- `/user` matches `/user`, but not `/user/`

What I currently did is create a regex for every route, and then match the current URI against that route regex.

What I currently have is:

[**My regex**](http://regexr.com/3fn6g)

In this example I try to make a regex for the route: `/post/{param1}/{param2}`. Meaning it should match `/post/` then a parameter and another parameter, but nothing **after** that parameter.

As you can see: `^(\/post\b)(\/.{1,}\/)(.{1,}\b)$` matches `/post/what-is-your-name/5`, and when I add another `/` it doesnt match anymore. However if you add characters **after** that regex again it starts to match again.

Meaning that:

- `/post/what-is-your-name/5/` doesn't match
- `/post/what-is-your-name/5/more` **does** match

Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish the first example?

I'm by far someone who knows a lot about regexes, if someone sees a better way to match URIs against routes then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you out

Regex: `^(?:\/post\b)(?:\/[\w]+){2}$`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gh8Wug/3)

Comment: This is kind of what I currently have, notice that this route should match `/post/{param}/{param}` and nothing more. If you add after that it still matches in mine and your example https://regex101.com/r/gh8Wug/2

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans Can you do one thing just update your post with more examples which you want to match or not

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans In this https://regex101.com/r/gh8Wug/2 can you mention which one you dont want to match

Comment: I'm trying to match `/post/{param}/{param}` nothing more than that. Now your an my regex match everything after it as well, meaning that /post/{param}/{param}/{param}/{param} also matches

Comment: so `/post/what-is-your-name/5/55555` and `/post/what-is-your-name/5/asdfasf` shouldn't match

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans Please check this https://regex101.com/r/gh8Wug/3 Hope it will work fine, if it is not working just mention in the link which one you dont want to get matched

Comment: That seems to be it :) Thanks for you help

Comment: During unit tests I figured that routes with a dash didnt match. Eg: /post/what-is-your-name if what-is-your-name is the parameter. So I changed any word character [\w] to everything except a forward slash [^/]

Comment: Either doing this `[^/] ` just add  `[\w\-] `, So expression will become `^(?:\/post\b)(?:\/[\w\-]+){2}$`

Comment: Ah yeah that seems much cleaner. I'm starting to get more of a feeling for regular expressions :) Thanks again